# Get_users who do not have meta_value

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am trying to search database with the `get_users` query and return users who's `meta_value` is everything except what's specified:

```
$unclaimed_users = get_users(array(
  'meta_key' => 'has_won',
  'meta_value' !=> '0'
));
```

For instance the users I need would have a meta value of anything apart from 0.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code is incorrect, try the following:

```
$unclaimed_users = get_users(array(
    'meta_key' => 'has_won',
    'meta_compare'  =>  '!=',
    'meta_value' => '0'
));
```

Comment: So meta_compare would see if the meta key does not hold the meta_value?

Comment: meta_compare defines the operator for meta_key, value '!=' indicates that the meta_key has_won must be different than value '0'

Comment: Thanks if I wanted to check multiple meta_keys / values in one array how would I do that : for instace     
    'meta_key' => 'a',
    'meta_value' => '0'
    'meta_key' => 'b',
    'meta_value' => '0'

Comment: In that case you would need to use meta_query parameter for more complex queries. More here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query